# How to split-view a single pdf in Acrobat so that two non-consecutive pages are side-by-side?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

##### Question:

How can I split a document so I can view one full page of the document on the left and a different page on the right?

##### Background:

I have a document with portrait-oriented pages, and want to view two full non-consecutive pages at a time.

##### Attempt and Current Behavior:

Window -> Split (splits the document horizontally, so I'm wasting half my screen and neither half of the split can display a full page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window > New Window` will give you 2 windows for the same PDF. Each window can display a different page in the PDF. Changes made in *either* window will be to the *same*, original, PDF. Merely position the windows so you can see them both.

I don't think it's possible to make "Split" split vertically, or any other way to view non-consecutive pages at the same time, short of duplicating the PDF on the hard drive and opening the original and the copy at the same time.

Note that *none* of this will translate to *any* other user viewing the PDF. It's not possible to set a "display" where 2 non-consecutive pages are shown to a reader at the same time. If the desire is to show users these 2 non-consecutive pages, then the original layout should be addressed. You can't do it in the PDF itself.